# Searchkick: Is there a good way to have two indices for the same model (one for searching and one for percolating)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'd like to have two search indices for the same model using Searchkick.  One index would be a normal search index and another would be an index used for running percolator queries against a different model's index.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Currently I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick callbacks: false

  after_commit :reindex_company

  def reindex_company
    reindex
    Company::Percolator.find(id).reindex
  end

  ...
end
```

And then for the second index:

```
class Company::Percolator < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "companies"

  MAPPINGS = {
    dynamic: "false",
    properties: {
      query: { type: "percolator" },
      text: { type: "text" }
    }
  }.freeze

  searchkick mappings: MAPPINGS, settings: ::Search::Utils::DEFAULT_SETTINGS

  def self.percolate(company)
    q = {
      query: {
        percolate: {
          field: "query",
          document: {
            text: company.search_data_for_percolator
          }
        }
      }
    }

    search(body: q.to_json, load: false)
  end

  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

I wanted to see if anyone knows a better way to do this as this solution depends on some undocumented apis in searchkick and requires some additions to ensure the indexes stay in-sync.